# Reading lines from a file in Java

Tags: java, string, file, lines

G'day:

I'm trying to use this:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path), encoding);
```

from https://stackoverflow.com/a/326440/2698254
and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29

but I'm having a bit of trouble implementing it.

My goal is to read all the lines from a file, then do some stuff with each line using that list (I imagine it works just like a vector...)

A few questions, because I'm getting a bunch of errors:

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("assets/unitsloc.txt"), Charset.defaultCharset());
```

This is what I've got so far, but the error markers are:

"Files cannot be resolved" - but there's no useful suggested import to make, same with Paths.

"The type List is not generic: it cannot be parametrized with arguments " -Do I need to initialise lines first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import the class before using it.

At the top of you class (after package), add

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
```

As [readAllLines](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.charset.Charset)) returns `List<String>` the warning about this should go away after correct importation.

Comment: but for both of those it says "the import java.nio.file cannot be resolved"... I'm using eclipse luna 4.4

Comment: These classes were introduced in java7 - are you using Java' or greater?

Comment: also, if it's relevant, I typed into terminal (I'm on OSX) java -showversion and got "  java version "1.6.0_65"  " Does this mean I'm running Java 6? Could this have anything to do with these classes not showing up?

Comment: Yes, These classes were introduced in java7

Comment: Okay, finally got eclipse to be using java7, but i'm still getting the last error regarding the type list not being generic etc...

Comment: Should only be a warning, unless you are importing some other List?

Comment: Yup that was it! Thank you so much. So would each element of the list now be a string that I can access and do whatever I want with?

Comment: Yes, each element of the list is a string

Comment: Thanks so much, works perfectly. Done and done! Cheers for the help.